# Numpy Matrix Modulo Index Extraction

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 2-dimensional matrix A, say

```
A = np.mat([[1,2,3,4], 
            [5,6,7,8],
            [9,10,11,12]])
```

how can I change all elements in row 1 with column index modulo 2 to 0? I.e., I would like to obtain

```
np.mat([[1,2,3,4], 
        [0,6,0,8], 
        [9,10,11,12]])
```

I have tried

```
A[1][np.arange(len(A))%2==0] = 0
```

which results in IndexError.

Comment: `A[1,np.arange(A.shape[1])%2==0] = 0`?

Comment: Be extra Careful with the [][] indexing of `np.mat`.  Look at `A[1]` first.

Comment: `A[1, ::2] = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

Column `index % 2 = 0` means that the index is an even integer. 
You can change the elements of the first row at even column indexes to 0 as follows:

```
A[1, ::2] = 0  # 2 is the step
```

If you want to do it as your (incorrect) `A[1][np.arange(len(A))%2==0] = 0`, you should change it to

```
A[1, np.arange(A.shape[1]) % 2 == 0] = 0
```

where `A.shape[1]` is the number of columns (whereas `len(A)` gives you the number of rows).